# Fetch 0 for the rows which does not have any data

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a user registration table where the registration count is stored month wise. Each month_key will have only single row.

We also have an employer_key column. Each employer_key will have (10 or 8 or 4 or 12 months) of data.

This is a postgreSQL table.

| month_key | registration_count |
| --- | --- |
| 202107 | 32 |
| 202103 | 19 |
| 202012 | 05 |
| 202008 | 54 |

My requirement is to pull total registration count for last 12 months per employer. The month range will vary as per the current month.

If any particular month does not have registration count data, then show 0 for it. Can we do it using PostgreSQL query.

For now I have written a simple query like -

```
select month_key, registration_count
from user_registrations ur 
where employer_key = 101 
and month_key between 202008 and 202107;
```

This query only returns those rows which has data. Can anyone please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the months you want and left join.  This is a bit tricky because of the month key.  Assuming it is an integer:

```
select month_key, coalesce(ur.user_registrations, 0)
from (select yyyymm,
             to_char(yyyymm, 'YYYYMM')::int as month_key
      from generate_series(date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '11 month', 
                           date_trunc('month', now()),
                           interval '1 month'
                          ) gs(yyyymm)
      ) ym left join
      user_registrations ur
      using (month_key);
```

If `month_key` is a string, you would use similar logic but the subquery would remove the `::int` to use a string.

Comment: month_key is integer.

Comment: This query is working, but not fully correct. It is returning 16 rows, instead 12. For some months it is returning multiple rows.

Comment: @sandeep . . . This would only return multiple rows if `user_registrations` has multiple rows in a month.  Your question makes no suggestion that this is possible, doesn't describe what logic you want, and your sample data has no duplicates.  The solution is to use `group by month_key` and the appropriate aggregation.  The question explicitly states:  "I have a user registration table where the registration count is stored month wise."

Comment: Ok... for better understanding I've made some changes to my question. Can you please take a look.